# Filter time select values to nearest 15 minutes in Angular

Tags: angularjs, time, filter

All.

I am building an Angular app where you can choose whether to select the time of day in 5, 7.5, 10 or 15 minute intervals. Because this is utilising select dropdowns, if the interval is set smaller than 15 minutes, it creates many, many options. What I want to do is to select the time in 15 minute increments and then use fine tuning up and down buttons to increment the time selection by the selected interval.

So far I have added the buttons and they work fine. All I need to do now is to filter the selection list so it will only display values that are in 15 minute blocks, i.e. 12:00, 12:15, 12:30, 12:45.

I should add that if the interval is set to 7.5 minute blocks, the time is formatted as such: 12:07:30

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/z3i8uZNeHoUSnUph6H7D?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.resetTime = function(){
    $scope.time = 12;
  }

  $scope.increaseTime = function(){
    $scope.time += $scope.interval/60;
  }

  $scope.decreaseTime = function(){
    $scope.time -= $scope.interval/60;
  }
});

app.filter('dateTime', function(){
  return function(input){
    if (input){
      var hours = Math.floor(input);
      input = (input - hours) * 60;
      var mins =  Math.floor(input);
      var secs = (input - mins) * 60;
      mins = (mins < 10 && mins > 0) ? '0' + mins : mins;
      return hours + ":" + mins;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
})
```

and in your markup

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="interval" ng-change="resetTime()">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
  </select>

  <hr/>

  <button ng-click="increaseTime();">Increase</button>
  <div>{{time | dateTime}}</div>
  <button ng-click="decreaseTime();">Decrease</button>
</body>
```

I didnt add the 12:07:30, hopefully you can do that on your own

Comment: Hi Yang! Sorry, I thought I would get an email notification for a response and then I forgot about it. Thanks for your response. :)